# Images sitting behind buttons to be viewed when the buttons are hovered

Tags: html, css

```css
.main {
 width: 1280px;
 background-color: antiquewhite;
 margin:auto;
}

.header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 background-color: black;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.homebutton {
 height: 80%;
 width:auto;
 float: left;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

.hometitle {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 color:white;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 150px;
 font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
 font-size: 33px;
 float:left;
 position:absolute;
 
}

h1 {
 font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: black;
 font-weight: 100;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}

.menubar {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 background-color:antiquewhite;
 float: left;
 /*PARENT CONTAINER */
}

.button1 {
 width: 25%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color:black;
 z-index: 1;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
 color:white;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-align: center;
 /* CHILD CONTAINER */
}

.button1:hover {
 background-color: antiquewhite;
 border: thick;
 
 color: black;
}


.buttonimage {
 width: 200px;
    height: auto;
 position:absolute;
 padding-left: 60px;
 padding-right: 60px;
 z-index: 0;
 top: -180px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 1.0s;
 animation: spin 2.8s linear infinite;
 overflow: hidden;
 /* CHILD CONTAINER */
}

@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }

.button1:hover .buttonimage {
 top:30px;
 opacity: 1;
 overflow: hidden
}

.heroimage {
 width: 100%;
 height: 800px;
 position: absolute;
 background-color:antiquewhite;
 float: left;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.imageslider {

}

.infocolumn {
 width: 20%;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: blue;
 float:left;
}

.footer {
 position:inherit;
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: white;
 float:left;
```

```html
</head>

<body>

<div class="main">

 
 <div class="header">
 
  <div class="homebutton">
   <img src="logo.png" height="120px" />
  </div>
  <div class="hometitle">
  Jet Black Cat Music 
  </div>
  
 
 </div>
 
 <div class="menubar">
 
  <div class="button1">
  Pre-orders
   <div class="buttonimage">
    <img src="vinyl_menu.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/>
   </div>
   
  </div>
  
  <div class="button1"> 
    In-Stores
    <div class="buttonimage">
    <img src="vinyl_menu.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="button1">
   Events
    <div class="buttonimage">
    <img src="vinyl_menu.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="button1">
   Contact
   <div class="buttonimage">
    <img src="vinyl_menu.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
 
 <div class="heroimage">
  
 </div>
 <div class="footer"> 
 </div>
 
</div>



</body>
```

**Edit: I messed around and almost got it back to where it is but now just cant get the buttons on top of the image the spins and moves down when i hover. The images were spinning records.**

this is my first time posting. Have been reading other threads and all the posts have been really helpful. I created a page pretty much to what I needed but I had flickering buttons that I couldn't fix, I ended up changing parts of my code to the point where now what I had is gone and I have no clue how to get back to where I was.

I'm trying to get a spinning image to sit behind each menu button, and when the menu button is hovered, the button moves down and part of the spinning image is revealed. As I said, I had this working but my buttons would just flicker.

Would really appreciate some help on how to fix this, I seem to just be going around in circles now

thanks

Comment: I haven't seen any animation property in your css to make the image spin. Also what kind of spinning are you speaking of? 3d spin 2d spinning?

Comment: Do you have an image of what you want it to look like? I created a plunker with your code and this is how it came out: https://plnkr.co/edit/xvSOtoCItKz5X95PUCLu?p=preview

Comment: @repzero I have updated it now and got it spinning. It's now just getting the buttons on top of the image instead of underneath.

Comment: thanks @user3554664 I was using vinyl/records and i have updated the code but need to work out how it's layered.

Answer (score 0):

Place all menu labels in a container

Apply a z-index property to your labels

Selectively style the topproperty of your labels in percentage

Snippet below

```css
  .main {
  width: 1280px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  margin: auto;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.homebutton {
  height: 80%;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.hometitle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 150px;
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
  font-size: 33px;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 100;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.menubar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  float: left;
  /*PARENT CONTAINER */
}

.button1 {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* CHILD CONTAINER */
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  border: thick;
  color: black;
}

.buttonimage img {
  width: 200px;
}

.buttonimage {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1.0s;
  animation: spin 2.8s linear infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* CHILD CONTAINER */
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(50%;
    0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(50%;
    0%);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.button1:hover .buttonimage {
  bottom: -200%;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button1:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  color: blue;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.button1:hover .label {
  top: 250px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.heroimage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imageslider {}

.infocolumn {
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}

.footer {
  position: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
```

```html
</head>

<body>

  <div class="main">


    <div class="header">

      <div class="homebutton">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSvPdDmWSbJtqGgr8qMOKew03yzJVKc9ZCYDbfzRKTnMrnrfwIsNg" height="120px" />
      </div>
      <div class="hometitle">
        Jet Black Cat Music
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="menubar">

      <div class="button1">

        <div class="label">Pre-orders</div>
        <div class="buttonimage">
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSvPdDmWSbJtqGgr8qMOKew03yzJVKc9ZCYDbfzRKTnMrnrfwIsNg" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" />
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="button1">
        <span class="label">In-Stores</span>
        <div class="buttonimage">
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSvPdDmWSbJtqGgr8qMOKew03yzJVKc9ZCYDbfzRKTnMrnrfwIsNg" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="button1">
        <span class="label">Events</span>
        <div class="buttonimage">
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSvPdDmWSbJtqGgr8qMOKew03yzJVKc9ZCYDbfzRKTnMrnrfwIsNg" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="button1">
        <span class="label">Contact</span>
        <div class="buttonimage">
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSvPdDmWSbJtqGgr8qMOKew03yzJVKc9ZCYDbfzRKTnMrnrfwIsNg" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="heroimage">

    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>

  </div>
  <br> 


</body>
```

Comment: thank you @repzero ! I haven't fixed it yet, but when I get around to it tonight I will let you know. many thanks!

Comment: thanks again @repzero ! I made some minor changes but what you posted gave me better understanding and allowed me to further tweak it. much obliged! :)